# What's the purpose of this RC filter?

Tags: circuit-analysis, filter, circuit-design, circuit-protection

The circuit is the following and i think this RC filter is used for anti debounce purposes but i'm not sure. Is it to prevent the optocoupler and the indicator LED from being "damaged" by the debounce effect of the switch?

And the circuit doesn't connect to any microcontroller so is that RC filter really necessary in this case?

[image]

Comment: The RC may be for debounce, but then very slow changing edges can be a cause of bounces. Assuming not too rapid switching, the two more important delays are determined by: the RC time constant going up with R1||R2 until one of the LEDs turns on; the RC time constant going down with R2||R3||R4 until one of the LEDs turns off. LEDs cannot be damaged by bouncing inputs alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The circuit is the following and i think this RC filter is used for anti debounce purposes but I'm not sure.

Yes, debounce but it could also filter / absorb any noise or spikes on the incoming line as the circuit is a low-pass filter.

> Is it to prevent the optocoupler and the indicator LED from being "damaged" by the debounce effect of the switch?

More likely just to debounce.

> And the circuit doesn't connect to any microcontroller so is that RC filter really necessary in this case?

It isn't directly connected to a micro-controller but presumably the opto-transistor is. Without the debounce circuit the opto-isolator would pass the contact bounce through to the following circuit giving multiple pulses. Presumably this would be a "bad thing" so they have prevented it.

Comment: Thanks! If for example R1 is 200 ohm and the capacitor C1 is 10uF, would the time constant be 2ms (=R1*C1)?

Comment: It would if there wasn't a pair of LEDs hanging off the capacitor. R1 is going to have to power these too. You'd need to figure out the parallel combination of the pair of LED resistors. If the maths gets too awkward then use a simulator such as LTSpice.

Comment: Without any calculations, would the time constant be higher or lower than 2ms?

Comment: Longer to charge. Shorter to discharge.