# What function does this resistor/capacitor arrangement provide in this reset circuitry

Tags: 555, reset

I have been trying to decipher what the arrangement of the resistor and capacitor does in the circuit below, but I am at a loss to explain it. Can someone explain to me what it is doing? The circuit itself is designed to hold a reset pin low for approximately 0.5 seconds to feed into a W65C02S CPU and support chips to provide a hardware reset function.

[image: Reset circuit]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the purpose of this RC filter?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/227378/whats-the-purpose-of-this-rc-filter)

Comment: @Jonathan. Yes, it does. I can go read about RC filters. Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand what the circuit consisting **only** of R3 and the RESET (so ignoring C4) switch does? Hint: R3 is a "pull up resistor". When the RESET switch is pressed, the voltage at the TRI input of the 555 is pulled low. When the switch is released, the voltage goes up again **immediately**. Now add C4, when the RESET button is pressed, again the input is pulled low. But now if we release the switch, the voltage does not rise immediately. C4 slows this down. So it takes longer for the voltage to increase. I think you're "overthinking" this simple circuit.

Comment: @bimpelrekkie Is the time constant for the capacitor to charge equal to 0.1 seconds (R3 * C4)? So the voltage begins to rise approx. 0.1 seconds after the button is pressed?

Comment: The circuit has the added benefit of "debouncing" the switch. Mechanical switches tend to quickly jiggle between connected/unconnected for about a msec during press or unpress. With this circuit every time the switch jiggles to the connected state the capacitor will reset (discharge) and the RC time constant will start over. Only after the switch stops bouncing will the final RC=.1sec occur.

Comment: *So the voltage begins to rise approx. 0.1 seconds after the button is pressed?* No, the voltage starts to rise **immediately** after releasing the switch, **however** the voltage will follow an exponential curve, read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit This is really basic level electronics so if this is new to you, get studying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments:

> Is the time constant for the capacitor to charge equal to 0.1 seconds (R3 * C4)?

Correct.

> So the voltage begins to rise approx. 0.1 seconds after the button is pressed?

Not quite. The voltage begins to rise **immediately the button is released**. It will be at 63% after one time constant (τ = RC) and that will be close to the switching threshold of the input.